# Zend Framework on nginx

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, nginx

The Zend Framework based site I have been working on is now being migrated to its production server. This server turns out to be nginx (surprise!). Naturally the site does not work correctly as it was developed on Apache and relies on an htaccess file.

My question is... anyone have any experience with this? Any ideas on how to translate what the htaccess file does to an nginx.conf file? I'm researching this but am hoping someone already has experience with this. Thanks!

EDIT: This is the current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What do you have in your .htaccess?

Comment: @gaoshan88 If stunti answered, why not accept his answer or is there anything else we can help you with?

Comment: Because, at the time, I had not had a chance to actually test stunti's suggestion.

Comment: also relevant: http://serverfault.com/questions/24243/nginx-support-for-htaccess-rewrite-rules-differences-from-apache

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it's a pretty old thread but it might help some people anyway.

Basically it redirects any 404 error to index.php, but if the file exists (type file) it will set the right root.

I did it from the top of my head. It might not be working right away, and you have to put the right path and fastcgi config. I also put everything back to index.php as it should work like that with Zend_Framework

```
error_page  404 = /index.php;

location / {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        root   /var/www;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     /var/www/index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a valid solution, because with the 404 error you'll be serving the page OK but in the header response you'll see the 404 status code, so it will mess up with your SEO, right?

Comment: @anders. You are right I have changed the example accordingly. Check the documentation here. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page I do it differently nowadays. catchall location for php and specific location for assets(images, css, js, html, ...)

Comment: -f (Nginx) check for the existence of a file. It's not the same than the Apache syntax: -s (regular file) OR -l (symbolic link) OR -d (directory). The correct equivalence is -e. And try_files should be used instead of if.

Comment: Apparently, using `If` inside `location` is bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil. This is for `Drupal` (http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal) but should work with `ZF` with minor changes.

Answer (score 29):

```
server {

 listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
 listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

 server_name  localhost;

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;

 root   /var/www/localhost/public;

 try_files $uri @php_index;

 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 #
 location @php_index {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/localhost/index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

It's recommended to use try_files when ever possible.

Comment: There are examples on the site of Nginx for try_files + PHP: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

Comment: This solution worked better for me than the accepted answer. Using the accepted answer version, no POST data was passed to PHP, probably due to the use of the error page. Using this solution, everything works as expected.

Comment: Many years later... this is indeed better. Note that this answer came 2 years after the question was asked which is why it was not the accepted one, just FYI.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know of any automatic/systematic way to convert the htaccess-file, you'll probably have to do it manually. The [Nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) is the best resource for nginx documentation.

**Edit:**
I'm running Zend Framework on Nginx myself now and the config looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name servername.com;

  root /var/www/zendapp/public;

  location / {
    index index.php;
  }

  # Deny access to sensitive files.
  location ~ (\.inc\.php|\.tpl|\.sql|\.tpl\.php|\.db)$ {
    deny all;
  }
  location ~ \.htaccess {
    deny all;
  }

  # Rewrite rule adapted from zendapp/public/.htaccess
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }

  # PHP scripts will be forwarded to fastcgi processess.
  # Remember that the `fastcgi_pass` directive must specify the same
  # port on which `spawn-fcgi` runs.
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
      root   /var/www/default;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the rewrite rule itself is very simple.

Answer (score 8):

This is "official", simple and works nice:

http://wiki.nginx.org/Zend_Framework#Time_for_nginx

Comment: Its losing the GET parameter... have a look at http://kfalck.net/2011/06/19/fix-empty-nginx-fastcgi-query-strings

Answer (score 7):

For staging server that could help ;)

```
            fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV staging;
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually i run a nginx with a drupal site that work like zend framework: one index.php as bootstrap

this is the rule (not tested on zend framework, just on drupal, but should be similar)

```
location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
                    break;
        }
    }

error_page  404              /index.php;
```

Comment: This is the basic rule for many apps in nginx, like Drupal. Good!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a subdirectory for your project like http://some.url/myproject/controller/, then you also need to add setBaseUrl to your bootstrap file.

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initSomeFancyName()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->setBaseUrl('/myproject'); // set the base url!
    }
}
```

The nginx rewrite would look like this:

```
location /myproject/ {
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/myproject/(.*)$ /index.php?$1? last;
  }
}
```

PS The question mark is not typo!

Answer (score 0):

If it were at all possible, I would recommend that they setup Apache on a nonstandard port accessible only from the Nginx box, and have Nginx proxy to Apache.

[Nginx Proxy documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule)

Comment: Wait… what?  Unless you have some <i>extremely</i> Apache-specific requirements (and rewrite rules are not Apache-specific), this suggestion is insane.

Comment: It isn't unreasonable to want nginx to serve the lightweight static content and have apache handle application logic.