# nginx redirects 302 instead of rewrite 200

Tags: php, nginx

If a user requests any .php file on my webserver I want his request (e.g. he requested mysite.com/testfile.php) to be handled by index.php

In index.php I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to see which page the user wants to see (e.g. /testfile.php), so the index.php can generate the appropriate html-code. Notice that testfile.php doesn't need to exist.

My problem is that I always get a redirect 302 to / when I try to request testfile.php (as a result $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is /). But what I want is a 200 OK for testfile.php and that index.php generates the right html-code for this.

This is a snippet from my buggy nginx.conf:

```
 server {
 [...]

   root /home/test;

   # When I go to mysite.com redirect my to mysite.com/
   location = / {
   index index.php;
   }

   # For any php file request: let index.php handle the request
   location ~ \.(php)$ {
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/test/index.php;
   }
 }
```

Anyone can help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files never exist you can do this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php
```

you can also rewrite the request like this:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

in both cases you should be able to read the original request with `PATH_INFO` or `REQUEST_URI`.

Have a look at these links for some more suggestions: http://drupal.org/node/110224, http://michaelshadle.com/2010/08/20/front-controller-patterns-and-nginx/, [Zend Framework on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376732/zend-framework-on-nginx)